# RadixSort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a question regarding radix sort algorithm. I found this implementation:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.io.*;

public class RadixSort {

    public static void radixSort(int[] data) {
        int z = 0  ;
        boolean flag = true;
        int divisor = 1;
        Queue[] buckets = new Queue[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            buckets[i] = new LinkedList();

        while (flag) {
            flag = false;
            // first copy the values into buckets
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                int hashIndex = (data[i] / divisor) % 10;
                if (hashIndex > 0)
                    flag = true;
                ((LinkedList) buckets[hashIndex]).addLast(new Integer(data[i]));
            }
            // then copy the values back into vector
            divisor *= 10;
            int i = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                while (!buckets[j].isEmpty()) {
                    Integer ival = (Integer) ((LinkedList) buckets[j])
                            .getFirst();
                    ((LinkedList) buckets[j]).removeFirst();
                    data[i++] = ival.intValue();
                }
            }
            z=z+1 ;

            System.out.print("Durchlauf " + z + " : ");
            for (int m  = 0; m < data.length; m++){

                System.out.print(data[m] + " ");


            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int[] arr = new int[15];
        System.out.print("original: ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1024);
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        radixSort(arr);


    }
}
```

I want to understand where the loop flow is defined. If I have a number of length 4, then the loop is running through fourth. Where is that defined?

Comment: Is this really *your* code or just copied/pasted from somewhere and trying to understand?

Comment: just trying to understand where loop will stoped

Comment: If you want to understand how it works, then one option is to step through it in a debugger.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of explanation you're looking for, but I hope this helps:

The outer `while` loop runs while `flag` is true. The `flag` will be false after the first run unless `hashIndex > 0` at least once when you're assigning values into buckets in your first `for` loop.

Then you have another`for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)` which will run 10 times for each value of j. The nested while loop `while (!buckets[j].isEmpty())` will run as many times as it has to, for each value of j.

Comment: thank you that's exactly what I wanted to know